# Unicode returning weird character in StringRedisTemplate java from redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to store portugese word `'como você está'` for a key in redis. Value is set in redis in unicode format `'como voc\x88 est\xa0184\'` in redis. But while fetching the value through `StringRedisTemplate` in Java am getting weird values like `'como voc� est�184'`. I tried the code below, but it is not working.

```java
template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
template.setHashValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
```

Here template object is of `StringRedisTemplate` class. Is there any mechanism to get the special characters back?

Comment: Not sure if your claim is correct. The value you have shown in question should be printed on console/file that does not support UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8 # the encoding of HTTP requests/responses
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true # enable http encoding support
spring.http.encoding.force=true # force the configured encoding
```

Comment: It will not work as data is coming wrong while fetching from redis directly. its not a spring boot thing. I tried, its not working